# Why have symbolic links between files in folders at same depth?

Tags: macos, symlink, macos-mojave, file-structure

I noticed that on OS X, the `/usr/local/Cellar` folder contains binaries installed using Homebrew, and that `/usr/local/opt` has symbolic links to a bunch of those binaries. I haven't used symbolic links much, but as I understand it, the purpose of them is to create a link in a convenient location to a file/folder that acts as a copy of that file/folder, without having to move that file/folder from its original location.

**So my questions are**:

1) Am I correct in my understanding of symbolic links there? ^^

2) If so ^^, why would you create symbolic links in one folder (`/usr/local/opt`) to binaries in another folder (`/usr/local/Cellar`) that is at a similar location/depth in the file structure? Under what circumstances would you use these symbolic links where you couldn't just use the binaries?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ (or possibly at https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew wants to keep things organized, therefore installing all its packages in one place (the cellar). Certain files of the tools you install with Homebrew are expected to be in certain places (e.g. in `/usr/local/opt`). A symbolic link is used here so when you update the Homebrew package in the cellar, the files linked in `/usr/local/opt` are also referring to the same updated version.

Also see the [Homebrew FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#can-i-install-my-own-stuff-to-usrlocal) for some info on the cellar

Comment: Hi @ikkentim, thanks for your response.
Re "Certain files of the tools you install with Homebrew are expected to be in certain places (e.g. in /usr/local/opt)": Am I correct then that while the full binaries are in /usr/local/Cellar, only certain files associated with those binaries are stored in /usr/local/opt? So the OS has some particular operations for which it needs the type of file in /usr/local/opt, and NOT the binaries themselves, and therefore looks in /usr/local/opt instead of /usr/local/Cellar?

Comment: The actual files are still in the cellar, but the symbolic links to them are in this one directory so, for example if the OS tried to find a certain library (.dylib) it will search this path because it is added to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` iirc